# error: symbol not found (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pdb-files

When I run my application, it says CXX0017 error: symbol not found, whereas that particular variable does not even exist in the code. I used it previously, and then removed it. Now, even after I cleaned and rebuilt the solution, it is still throwing it. I've checked the modules, and the PDB file is correct. Also, I deleted the PDB file and built it again, but no use. This is in Visual Studio 2010. I've searched about this, and some say that this is a bug related to Visual Studio 2010. I wanted to ask if anyone found a solution to this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Where does it say this error? What are the exact steps that cause this error to be shown? Have you tried deleting the .suo file? (This will clear all your breakpoints, bookmarks, etc. as a side effect.)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution? (Build -> Clean solution)

Comment: @Mohammad he says he cleaned and rebuild the solution, so that is obvious, isn't it?

Comment: How did you check that the PDB file is correct? I am just curious because I never found any information about the file structure.

Comment: @Cameron, This is just shown when I debug the application. I couldn't find the .suo file though, I can only see the .sdf and .sln files in the project directory. I feel like Visual Studio is caching the .pdb file info, and running my previous code although when I run the newer code.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun, yes I cleaned it and tried it but doesnt work.

Comment: @user: Do you mean a dialog box pops up when you start debugging with this message? The .suo is a hidden file in the same folder as the .sln (close VS before deleting it).

Comment: @harper, I'm sorry what I said was vague. I meant that the pdb file is being loaded correctly.

Comment: @Cameron, the symbol not found error is shown in the debug information. A pop-up is shown with the "access violation reading location 0xfffffff" error..

Comment: @martijnn2008 I saw the 'rebuilt' part, but I missed the 'cleaned' part.

Comment: Also, the pop-up says Unhandled exception at 0x7398A465 (winspool.drv) in .exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000DE50.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it working. All I had to do was to remove watch when that error occurred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CXX0017` is a debugger error issued when a breakpoint watch uses an identifier that is not available. Remove or edit your breakpoints to stop using that identifier and the problem should go away.

Comment: Thank you so much! All I had to do was to remove watch when those errors occurred. And then it was all good!